# Google App Engine version numbers?

Tags: google-app-engine, version

How do App Engine version numbers work? Are they only integers? Can I use floats? Can I reuse old version numbers?

Comment: Going by the error message, it has to match expression '^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'. If I'm reading the regexp correctly, it means that it can contain lowercase letters, digits, and hyphens, be 1 to 63 characters long, and not start with a hyphen. So you can't use floats like 1.1, but you can use 1a, 1b... or 1-1, 1-2.... And you can reuse old version numbers, it just means that you'll overwrite that old version instead of overwriting the latest version.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From the manual:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Required_Elements

> A version specifier for the
>   application code. App Engine retains a
>   copy of your application for each
>   version used. An administrator can
>   change which major version of the
>   application is default using
>   Administration Console, and can test
>   non-default versions before making
>   them default. The version specifier
>   can contain letters, digits, and
>   hyphens.
>
> Each version of an application retains
>   its own copy of app.yaml. When an
>   application is uploaded, the version
>   mentioned in the app.yaml file being
>   uploaded is the version that gets
>   created or replaced by the upload.

Comment: @Henrik P. Hessel: your answer still has some merit though. Atleast prefixing with integers makes sorting a lot easier for your own management :)

Comment: I never used anything else than Integers on the GAE. Using A, B, C and so on (or even strings) just doesn't feel natural.

Comment: Note that if using letters, they must be lower case.  For example, capital 'X' version will fail with this message:  

`Unable to assign value 'X' to attribute 'version':
Value 'X' for version does not match expression '^(?:^(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,62}[a-z\d]$)$'`

Comment: @Wolph when I create a new Version (2) and deploy it i see activity on it. However I still see activity on the previous version Version 1(default) even after I manually shut down all Version 1 instances

Comment: As long as the old version is the default it will automatically respawn. If you make the new version the default it should die out eventually.

Answer (score 7):

In order to access a version of your app other than the default one, add **#.** before your app url as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8549546/129202
This is useful for testing new versions before you make them live.

> If the version of app is 2 and your app URL is appname.appspot.com
>   then URL 2.appname.appspot.com will give you access to version 2 of
>   your app.

Comment: Please note google has changed the way versioned URLs work. You should instead use `2-dot-appname.appspot.com` , otherwise you'll get a security warning.

Comment: It seems even if you delete the version1 of your app it doesn't assign the default url to version 2.

Answer (score 4):

You can increment it when you pushing a new release. See below for reference.

> When you build a new major release of
>   an application that is already running
>   on App Engine, you can upload the new
>   release as a new version. The old
>   version will continue to serve users
>   until you switch to the new version.
>   You can test the new version on App
>   Engine while the old version is still
>   running.

Edited: Didn't remove my answer because there're some good comments on it.

Comment: That's incorrect. You can use letters, digits and hyphens in the version. No need for integers.

Comment: For the GAE app that I have in SVN, I use the repository revision number. If I was using git I suppose I'd use a checksum, in which case I'd prefix it with what you suggest, an integer incremented for each release uploaded.

Comment: Even after pushing out a new release with a new version and manually shutting down all old instances, for some reason app engine keeps recreating the old version