# Testing uploaded app, other than default version

Tags: google-app-engine, testing, version

Can you test an uploaded version of an app, other than the "default" version?

I'm told it can be: WoLpH [Google App Engine version numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848131/google-app-engine-version-numbers)

But I can't find it in the dashboard or the doco.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the version of app is `2` and your app URL is `appname.appspot.com` then URL `2.appname.appspot.com` will give you access to version `2` of your app.

Comment: Check "Domains" section of article:  http://cloudspring.com/understanding-google-app-engine-gae-java-api-part-1-landscape-overview

Comment: For Live URLs of various versions check http://tinypic.com/r/zvocr6/5 and for changing the XML file so you can upload your codebase to a specific version check: http://tinypic.com/r/2vvurmd/5

Comment: Hi, Can different version have access to the the different data? For example i want that the version 2 of the app engine should access different data set and version should access different data set.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal AFAIK - the data can not be different, only app code can be. And if you are using object entities (NoSQL) data - then you can always maintain version number on your entities to achieve different data being accessed by different versions of app

Answer (score 6):

As Vishal already said correctly (+1), you can prepend the version identifier to your url, so if your version is "version", the URL will be version.appname.appspot.com (app versions are strings, not numbers, although the string "2", is perfectly ok too).

To select another version from [the Dashboard](https://appengine.google.com/), just select the main application first, then use the second dropdown at the top of the page to select the version. This will show you the dashboard of another version, without changing the default (active) version.

[image: where to select a version]

Important considerations to keep in mind:

- However, the main gotcha that I would like to mention, is that **you're using the same Datastore** of the live version. This can be a good thing, if you want to browse your application, but is not very recommendable if you want to insert test data that could potentially mess the public view.
- You're also **using the same task queues and cron**, so you've to be careful of unintended consequences, should your application version update them.

If the problems mentioned above are important to you, you may consider to deploy another application to use for testing instead. In this way you'll be completely separated by the live environment.

Comment: +1 good answer and followup question. What is the best approach to separate the data from the debug version and the live one?

Comment: Thanks you so much for the clearly telling that the the same datastore will be used, @Jonny i think new project can be created on Google Developer console and then changing the application-id in the code will do work.

Answer (score 3):

Note that double wildcards for appspot.com are no longer supported (`*.*.appspot.com`). To test different version than default use `version-dot-` prefix.

```
appname.appspot.com          // default
2-dot-appname.appspot.com    // version 2
```

Comment: Yes! Amazing, have been looking for this for hours.

Comment: You will also need to adjust end points for any google integration - for example authentication, recaptcha etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the menu there is section Main > Versions and there you can choose the version then "Make default". Of course to have more than one version available there you have to change the version before deploying(as far as I remember you can do this in one of xml files).

Or you mean to have default version, but test another one?

Comment: Not adding a vote down, but it's not necessary to make version default for testing. You can keep your default version and test other versions at the same time, check my answer